# How to fetch all roles in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, roles

I wanted to fetch all roles in Netsuite via Rest/Soap API.
Currently im able to fetch roles through the employee records but not roles directly.
And also is there any way we can fetch the permission of a Role as well?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4623992425.html#bridgehead_4624464502 I found this link, hope this helps

Comment: related?: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4623992425.html#bridgehead_4624464502

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you have the username (email) and password of the netsuite user.

There's a special `/roles` api (`https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles`) that allows you to list all netsuite roles associated with a user. Here's [some example code demonstrating](https://github.com/NetSweet/netsuite/blob/c3dae8ee4ca827c3aa6ee969c8f6f895a8bda10c/lib/netsuite/rest/utilities/roles.rb#L8-L16) how to use this API.

Answer (score 0):

you can also, check all roles with SuiteQL
https://<<"yourAccount">>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql

POST this JSON as body

```
{ "q": "select  * from  role"}
```

you must have a role with enough permission